# Editing My Questions and Reached Daily Limits of 5

Tags: support, edits, rate-limiting

I am currently checking all my posts in SO for errors so I can make corrections to them. However, I have reached the daily limit of 5 edits for today.

I would like to continue on what I am doing. Is there anything that I can do to lift this restriction aside from waiting for another 24 hours?

Comment: @Oded, of course it's a feature not a bug. :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165885/165773

Comment: I guess I will have to do this on a daily basis then.

Comment: Oh I just realized that I'm on the cross-hairs of the moderators now. I am not doing anything bad. :)

Comment: Captain wagging finger: If you need to edit so many questions to fix problems, you might want to think about taking more time to write them and not have to run into this limitation altogether ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, you'll need to wait the 24 hours to continue editing more old posts.

Recent posts are not subject to the restriction.